# Why doesn’t my toe consistently register as a touch?

Tags: iphone

I was sitting on my couch watching Harry Potter with my kids, even though I didn’t want to. My phone flipped on to the floor when I got up for something. When I can back I wanted to see if my friend texted me so instead of bending over I touched it with my toe so the screen would turn on. I couldn’t get it to register as a touch. Since the first time, it takes about 5-10 touches before the screen comes on.

What gives? Do I have more electric charge in my fingers than I do my toes? How convenient.

[image]

Comment: If my phone has gone inti screensaver then I have to push the home button - did you do that? From the image - no, so it won’t wake...

Comment: If I reach down and touch it with my finger it’ll wake. Every time. Not with the tow though.